# Rewarded Videos doesn't load the first time but loads after

Tags: java, android, admob

My App has a button to open reward videos >> when this button is pressed for the first time, it toasts "Check your Internet connection", when hit the second or third time, it shows the video with no problems

```
    MobileAds.initialize(getActivity(), getString(R.string.VID_App_ID));
    mRewardVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(getActivity());
    mRewardVideoAd.loadAd(getString(R.string.VID_App_Unit_ID), new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.TestDeviceID))
            .build());
    mRewardVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);
    loadRewardedVideoAd();
```

Here are the methods used :

```
 private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        mRewardVideoAd.loadAd(getString(R.string.VID_App_Unit_ID), new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(getString(R.string.TestDeviceID))
                .build());
    }



   @OnClick(R.id.button_more_money)
    public void more_money() {
        if (mRewardVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
            mRewardVideoAd.show();
        } else
            { 
             Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            loadRewardedVideoAd();
               }

    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mRewardVideoAd.resume(getActivity());
        super.onResume();
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }
```

Edit: Solved 
- It took some time and the solution was to load at onCreate()
Thanks to Martin De Simone and Avi Levin

Comment: Which ad-network are you using inside AdMob mediation waterfall?

Comment: Your `else` inside `more_money` should have curly braces or the last line will execute unconditionally.

Comment: @AviLevin I don't know actually, This my first time to use ads, I'll figure out what I'm using now

Comment: @shmosel edited

Comment: @AviLevin I don't need the mediation part right now, I test it with the defaults videos of Admob . Is it related to the problem? Do you mean that the problem is with the connection with Admob ?

Comment: @AhmadHisham - I wrote you an answer. I recommend working with few ad network and not just with the default Google RV ads inside AdMob. You can maximize your income and ad availability by doing so. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rewarded videos take time to load, your code is fine, the first time you are pressing, the video is loading and then when you press probably the video has already loaded.

Try to toast something in the onAdLoaded to check this

Comment: That was a life saver, It took some time and the solution was to load at onCreate()

Comment: I did but I'm less than 15 reputations right now, when i reach it i'll come back and vote it

Comment: I just upvoted your question, now you are 16 reputation (:

Answer (score 1):

As Martin said, RV ad takes a time to load. basically, it needs to download ~30-second video which takes sometimes few second.

I recommend using the SDK provided RewardedVideoAdListener interface which will help you know when the ad is ready to show. furthermore, it will help you to understand the AdMob rewarded video ad's life cycle.

In order to use it you need to do the following phases:

1. Implement RewardedVideoAdListener listener in your java class
2. Override the following methods (I used `Toast` UI messages for visualization, it can be deleted)

Code:

```
@Override
public void onRewarded(RewardItem reward) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewarded! currency: " + reward.getType() + "  amount: " +
        reward.getAmount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

BTW: before a show call, I recommend using `isLoaded()` method in order to if the AdMob is ready to show something, for example:

```
if (mAd.isLoaded()) {
    mAd.show();
}
```

More information can be found inside Google AdMob [doc's](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, finished successfully